# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in jquery in hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code:

```
    <script>
        $( "#ajax_res_{$id_actif}_{$k}" ).before({
            $( ".cart_quantity_button" ).hide(); // in this line
        });
        $( "ajax_res_{$id_actif}_{$k}" ).before({
            $( ".cart_quantity_input" ).hide(); // in this line
        });
    </script>
```

I'm getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string error` in my JavaScript and I honestly can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

I have looked at the similar questions, but I'm unable to find a solution. The error is coming in the line highlighted with an asterisk below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed a Javascript variable in a string you need to use ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
$(`#ajax_res_${id_actif}_${k}`)
```